# Что значат фигурные скобки в котлин?

Tags: kotlin

Я новичок в котлине и не могу понять, что делают фигурные скобки в котлин при вызове функции MyApplicationTheme. Функция принимает всего два параметра, но я в фигурных скобках могу писать любой код и в любом количестве. Вот пример:

```
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        val message = remember{mutableStateOf("")}
        val message2 = remember{mutableStateOf("2")}
        val v = print("print")
        Greeting("Android")
        val hello = {println("Hello Kotlin")}
        val printer = {message: String -> println(message)}
        GreetingAll("Hi")
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApplicationTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),content: @Composable() () -> Unit)
{
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это то же самое, что

```
MyApplicationTheme(content = { ... })
```

Это ужасно, и к этому надо привыкнуть.